# AlarmManager and notification not appearing

Tags: android, android-studio

Somehow, the logic of the code seems correct but then no notification pops up for a date/time the user has selected. Need some advice on this. I'm using a class extending a fragment. Whenever i set a time e.g. 8.16am, 8.15am(now) , i wait and the alarm will not ring. I've already added receiver name in my manifest. please please help!!

```
 public void oneTime(int day, int month, int year, int min, int hour ){


    int xx= (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Toast.makeText( getContext() ,  "TIME" + xx , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,min );
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, day);


    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ToDoAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent examIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext() , xx , intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getContext().ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), examIntent);


}
```

This is how my AlarmManager looks like

public class ToDoAlarm  extends BroadcastReceiver{

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    // Vibrate the mobile phone
    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context
            .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(2000);
    Uri at = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context,at );
    r.play();

    NotificationManager mNM;
    mNM = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp

    PendingIntent examIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, About.class), 0);
    // Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.four, "Demo !",System.currentTimeMillis());
    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification



    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Medication Reminder")
            .setContentText("Remember to eat your medicine!")

            .setContentIntent(examIntent);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
    mNM.notify(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, notification);



}
```

}

Comment: You are setting the alarm for current time. Try setting it for a later time, for example: `code`alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis() + 1000, examIntent);

Comment: I have a date and time picker, when i choose the date today e.g 8.16am now and set the the alarm to 8.17am, the alarm still does not sound even though i've added the + 1000